# How to automatically generate Sequence diagram for NUnit project using Sparx Enterprise Architect

Tags: nunit, uml, specflow, enterprise-architect, sequence-diagram

Hi How do we Autogenerate Sequence diagrams using Enterprise architect software? I have gone through article http://blog.lieberlieber.com/2012/03/13/tutorial-nunit-and-sequence-diagram-recording-in-enterprise-architect-9-3/ but in that blog, its  not shown how to generate diagrams using NUnit project. He has mentioned that we could do using nUnit, but its not explained how to do. Also is there any way to generate same diagrams using SpecFlow project?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Sparx EA uses debug symbol output to identify sequences of calls between in-memory objects and build a sequence diagram, e.g. from the call stack. To leverage this you need to attach EA into a process that is emitting debug symbols (in a similar way to how you might attach an IDE into a process to debug it) and use the EA 'debug' tools to add breakpoints, step through lines and so on. How you get hold of these tools depends on the version of EA that you're using (ribbon, menus etc often get changed between versions), but somewhere you will find the Debugger window. From there just follow your nose.

Comment: Thanks muszeo will try it out